# Proof that you can multiply (divide) by a scalar in a vectorial equation

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I want to prove that I can divide both sides of an equation with vectors by only using the properties of a vector space ([definition and properties of a vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition_and_basic_properties)) and the cancellation law for a sum of vectors (**w**=**v** iff **w**+**u**=**v**+**u**).

Let α be a nonzero real number and let **v**, **w** be vectors that belong to a vector space **V**. I want to prove that

> α**v** = α**w** iff **v** = **w**

I would proceed by saing that, for the cancellation law for a sum of vectors, i can add -(α-1)**v** to both sides of α**v** = α**w**:

> α**v** = α**w** iff α**v**-(α-1)**v**=α**w**-(α-1)**v** iff **v**= α**w**-(α-1)**v**

then i do the same with -(α-1)**w**, so i get

> **v**-(α-1)**w** = α**w**-(α-1)**v**-(α-1)**w** iff  **v**-(α-1)**w** = **w**-(α-1)**v**

By putting β:=α-1, i can say that **v**-β**w** = **w**-β**v** and, because by assumption α**v** = α**w** for a generic real number α, than also β**v**=β**w**.

So i can add β**w** to both sides of the equation thanks to the cancellation law for sum of vectors:

> **v**-β**w**+β**w** = **w**-β**v**+β**w** iff **v**=**w**

**IMPORTANT: MY DOUBT**

My question is: is this proof correct?
It seems wrong to me to use the assumption α**v** = α**w** in the proof, but I think that, since it is an assumption, it’s true and I can use it. The thing is that I remember that “using an assumption of a bi-implication to prove the bi-implication itself” was used as an example to a logical fallacy or a common basic error in proofs, but I can’t find the source of that.

**NOTE**

I do not have yet a theorem that says that I can multiply (by a scalar) both sides of an equation with a vector, I only have the properties of a vector space and the cancellation law of the sum of vectors.

Multiplying both sides of an equation by a scalar is not a solution to my problem, because we have proof that we can do it and still get an equivalent equation only for algebraic equations (or equations where the variable is a number). My goal is to prove that also for equations with vectors.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your question, but if $\alpha\neq 0$, why not just multiply each side of the equation by $1/\alpha$ ? Since the scalar are a field, you know that the inverse exists as soon as $\alpha\neq 0$.

Comment: I agree with Florian above. As for your attempted proof, it essentially boils down to "if αv=αw for general α, then v=w" which is more easily shown true by taking α=1. That is however not a proof for the equivalence of αv=αw and v=w for a specific non-zero α so your doubts are justified. Note that the two statements αv=αw and v=w are not equivalent when α=0 so any correct proof would have to rely on α being non-zero (at least for the rightwards implication).

Comment: @FlorianIngels I just edited my question, see the **note**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $\alpha \cdot v=\alpha \cdot w$$\iff$$v=w$, you also need $\alpha\neq 0$ condition. Let $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}-\{0\}$ and $v,w\in V$. Then $$v=1\cdot v=(\alpha^{-1}\cdot \alpha)\cdot v= \alpha^{-1}\cdot (\alpha\cdot v)= \alpha^{-1}\cdot (\alpha\cdot w)= (\alpha^{-1}\cdot \alpha)\cdot w= 1\cdot w=w.$$ Thus $v=w$. If $v=w$, then clearly $\alpha \cdot v=\alpha\cdot w$.

Comment: Thanks, I understood your answer, but why did you say “if v=w, then clearly αv=αw”? Is it just a way to end the proof and highlight the result of that series of equivalences or…? (maybe it’s just a problem of language, since I’m not from an english speaking country)

Comment: @JacopoSenoner $v=w$ implies $av=aw$ as the symbols $v,w$ are equal, ‘principle of substitution’ I think it is called

Comment: In $A$$\iff$$B$ problems, we have to show $A\Rightarrow B$ and $A\Leftarrow B$. In other word, you have to prove two implication. I hope, your and mine english will get better with time. I read your note. “I can multiply (by a scalar) both sides of an equation with a vector”. Let $v=w\in V$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$. By definition of scalar multiplication, $\alpha \cdot v\in V$. Since $v=w$, we have $\alpha \cdot v= \alpha \cdot w$. It looks like we multiply scalar $\alpha$ in both of side equation, but we have used much more fundamental fact ($v=w$).

Comment: @user264745 Ahh now it’s clear, thank you for the explanation